# selected drop down value not shown after this.form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm using this.form.submit() for form submit.I have selected any values from dropdown but its not shown as selected.Here is my code.Please help.

```
<div class="select-dropdown">
    <form  action="<?= base_url() ?>current_tender_list" method="POST">
    <select  name ="tenders" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="Archived">Archived Tenders</option>
    <option value="Closed">Closed Tenders</option>
    <option value="Current">Show Current Tenders</option>
    </select>
   </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Because , your form submits and page gets refresh so selected value are lost .

Comment: @Swati any solution??

Answer (score 1):

You have to set then selected="selected" in your HTML.

Try something like this:

```
  <div class="select-dropdown">
    <form  action="<?= base_url() ?>current_tender_list" method="POST">
    <select  name ="tenders" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option <?php if( $result['tenders'] =='Archived'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="Archived">Archived Tenders</option>
        <option <?php if( $result['tenders'] =='Closed'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="Closed">Closed Tenders</option>
        <option <?php if( $result['tenders'] =='Current'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?> value="Current">Show Current Tenders</option>
    </select>
   </form>
 </div>
```